# How to delete rows from a SharePoint list using PnP PowerShell?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, powershell, modern-experience, pnp-powershell

I am using PnP PowerShell to access the SharePoint Online environment.

How can I delete rows of a SharePoint list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you are asking for:

```
Remove-PnPListItem -List "[Your list Title goes here]" -Identity ($TheItemId)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can delete a list item/row using below command:

```
Remove-PnPListItem -List "Demo List" -Identity "1"
```

Where `-Identity` is the ID of the list item, or actual `ListItem` object.

**Microsoft Official Reference**: [Remove-PnPListItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/remove-pnplistitem)

If you want to remove all items from a SharePoint Online list then check below reference:

[Remove all items from a SharePoint Online list using PnP PowerShell](https://www.spguides.com/remove-all-items-from-a-sharepoint-online-list-using-pnp-powershell/)

**Additional Reference**: [Get-PnPListItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnplistitem) - Using this command first you can fetch the list items (single item or multiple items) and then you can delete the list item using above command.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Get-PnPListItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnplistitem?view=sharepoint-ps#outputs) get all items you want to delete,
then you can use [ListItem.DeleteObject](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ee540290(v=office.15)) method in the loop, or you could choose use [Remove-PnPListItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/remove-pnplistitem?view=sharepoint-ps) in the loop.